# My weirdly non-working C code for getting a word

Tags: c, struct

With this structure definition:

```
struct word {
    char *cont; //content of the word
    char *wsp; //whitespace following the word
    int ctr;
};
```

for a word, I'm trying to write a function to get the first word from stdin with all the whitespace following it. Here it is:

```
struct word *getword(){
    char cont[WORDLIM];
    char wsp[WORDLIM];
    cont[0] = '\0';
    wsp[0] = '\0';
    if (peekchar() == EOF) return NULL; //peekchar defined elsewhere as getting a char and ungetc-ing it

    REPEAT{ //macro for for(;;)
            char c = getchar();
            char buf[2];
            buf[0]=c;
            buf[1]='\0';
            if (c == '\n' || c == ' '){
                    strcat(wsp, buf);
                    if (peekchar() != '\n' && peekchar() != ' '){
                            struct word *toret;
                            toret = malloc(sizeof(struct word));
                            toret->cont = cont;
                            toret->wsp = wsp;
                            toret->ctr = -1;
                            printf("---%s---\n", toret->wsp); //just for debugging
                            return toret;
                    }
                    continue;
            }
    }
    printf("PANIC PANIC PANIC THIS IS GOING WROOOOONG!!!!!\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Now the fun thing is that I can get the correct output of whitespace in the just for debugging line, but when I attempt to access getword()->wsp, I get random garbage. Even more interestingly, getword()->cont works...

I'm a really new newbie to C...what did I do wrong?

Comment: `char cont[WORDLIM]` and `char wsp[WORDLIM]` are local to `getword`, they don't exist anymore after the function returned. Then the `cont` and `wsp` members of `*toret` become dangling pointers, accessing them is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
REPEAT{ //macro for for(;;)
```

Lose that macro post-haste.  Using the preprocessor to de-uglify C syntax is a recipe for heartburn.  Just use `for(;;)` or `while(1)`.  The compiler is usually smart enough to turn it into an unconditional jump.

As for your problem:

```
toret->cont = cont;
toret->wsp = wsp;
```

The `cont` and `wsp` arrays are declared locally to the `getword` function; once the function exits, the arrays cease to exist, and any pointers to them are no longer valid.  What you'll need to do is allocate memory for the `cont` and `wsp` members of `toret` in addition to the memory for `toret` itself.

```
toret = malloc(sizeof(struct word));
if (toret) // ALWAYS check the result of a `malloc` call
{
  toret->cont = malloc(strlen(cont) + 1);
  if (toret->cont)
    strcpy(toret->cont, cont);
  toret->wsp = malloc(strlen(wsp) + 1);
  if (toret->wsp)
    strcpy(toret->wsp, wsp);
  ...
}
```

Note that when you need to free the memory for the struct, you'll first need to free the memory for the `cont` and `wsp` members.

Comment: @EricDong: `ctr` works because it's not a pointer.  `cont` *appears* to work because the memory it points to hasn't been overwritten by the time you access it (as opposed to `wsp`).  However, it's still a mistake.  The behavior on accessing memory through an invalid pointer is *undefined*, meaning that neither the compiler nor the implementation are required to do anything in particular in response to it; the program may crash outright, it may appear to work just fine (such as for `cont`), or it may produce garbage output (such as for `wsp`).

Answer (score 4):

You're returning pointers to memory that's gone out of scope.

You dynamically allocate a `struct word`,  but the actual characters are held in the `wsp` array. Once your function returns, that is out of scope, so could contain anything.

Answer (score 1):

`*toret` is a dangling pointer here in your program

Comment: Actually, no: `toret` is a valid pointer to malloc'd memory. But `*toret` *contains* some dangling pointers.